A Corollary of Cauchy-Hadamard
Cauchy-Hadamard's Theorem, which follows immediately from the Root Test, says that if $\sum_{j=0}^\infty a_j(x - c)^j$ is a (say, real) power series, then if $A = \limsup_n |a_n|^{1/n}$, then $\rho = 1/A$ is the radius of convergence of the series (where $1/0$ should be interpreted as $\infty$).
On page 208 of Krantz, "Real Analysis and Foundations," 4th ed, the author lists the following result as an immediately corollary with no proof:
For a series as above, a number $\rho$ is the radius of convergence of the series iff for every $0<R<\rho$, there exists $C_R>0$ such that $|a_j| \leq C_R/R^j$ (presumably for all $j$).

This seems to be incorrect. Should we not require that $\rho$ is maximal with respect to this property?

I cannot construct a rigorous proof of either direction of this result.


Best attempts: Throughout, assume the radius of convergence is positive and finite; the fringe cases are less interesting. For the forward direction, let $\rho$ be the radius of convergence. Then $\rho = 1/A$ by Hadamard. Let $0 < R < \rho$. Then $A < 1/R$. We know that, given $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $N$ such that if $j > N$, then $|a_j|^{1/j} < A + \epsilon$ by standard facts about limsup. This tells us that $|a_j| < (A + \epsilon)^j$ for these $j$, but I do not see how to proceed from here.
For the other direction, I am not sure how to proceed at all.

I agree with you on (1). If the property holds for all $0<R<\rho$ it clearly holds, say for $0<R<\rho/2$, so I would say the proposition should be: the series converges for $|x-c|<\rho$ iff that property holds, so the radius of convergence is the supremum of such $\rho$'s.

Call $\rho_0$ the radius of convergence, assumed positive and finite. Suppose the series converges for $|x-c|<\rho$ and $0<R<\rho$. Then $\rho\le\rho_0$ so $R<\rho_0$. By Cauchy-Hadamard formula
$$
\displaystyle{R<\rho_0=\frac 1{\limsup \sqrt[n]{|a_n|}}}
$$
or, equivalently,
$$
\displaystyle{\limsup |a_n|<\frac 1{R^n}}
$$
Therefore, for all but a finite number of terms you have
$$
|a_n|<\frac 1{R^n}.
$$
Let the possible terms greater than  or equal to $1/R^n$ be
$$
|a_{n_1}|,\dots |a_{n_k}|.
$$
Then the proposition holds with
$$
C_R=\max\{\max_j R^{n_j}|a_{n_j}|, 1\}.
$$
In the opposite direction, suppose you know that
$$
|a_j|<\frac{C_R}{R^j}
$$
for each $R<\rho$ and some positive constants $C_R$. Choose any $\rho_1<\rho$. Then choose $\rho_1<R<\rho$. When $|x-c|=\rho_1$, your series has the numerical series
$$
C_R\left(\frac{\rho_1}{R}\right)^n
$$
which is a convergent geometric series, as its majorant. Therefore, your series converges for any $x$ with $|x-c|=\rho_1<\rho$, as was to be proved.
